Is a semigroup with following property a group?
Let G be a semigroup with the property below:
$$\forall a\in G\ \forall b \in G\ \exists c\in G\ (abc=cba=a).$$
Can we always say that G is a group?
I'm expecting some counterexamples but I couldn't find any.
Does anyone have an idea?

No. Let $S$ be a semigroup with at least two elements and multiplication $xy=y$ for all $x,y$. For any $a$ and $b$, pick $c=a$ and then $abc=c=a=aba = cba$.

@ArturoMagidin: Please feel free to post your comment as an answer. I know you can still see my deleted one: I have elected not to undelete it. As a matter of personal policy, I don't post answers to questions which change substantially after being asked (especially since this one already had a correct, upvoted answer from user14111 at the time) :(
